# Continuously getting the runtime error 1004 when using Advanced Filter in VBA "AdvancedFilter method of Range class failed"

Tags: excel, vba

you all were a great help with my last issue, so I figured Id ask another question. I am currently creating a code that keeps track of a mailroom's inventory. The code that I am working on is a textbox that whenever something is typed, it copies the value to the excel and it triggers an advanced search. I want to use xlfiltercopy to prevent visual damage to the excel sheet and so it is easier to update the listbox in the userform with the filtered information. Please let me know if you can find a reason that the error "AdvancedFilter method of Range class failed"

EDIT: If possible, I would like to email the entire excel to someone to see if the program works on another computer. I cannot physically think of a way to get it to work. Please consider it!

```
' Input on the 2nd page
' This code will update the list box below automatically as you type a name
Private Sub TextBox5_Change()

If Me.TextBox5.Value = "" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim wks As Worksheet
Set wks = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Mail_Inventory")
Dim rgData As Range
Dim rgCriteria As Range
Dim rgOutput As Range
Dim currentinventory As Long
Dim filteredcurrent As Long
Dim temp As Long
temp = wks.Range("AS1").Value

If temp > 0 Then
    wks.ListObjects("CurrentFiltered").DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
End If

wks.Range("AP6").Value = Me.TextBox5.Value
currentinventory = wks.Range("A1").Value

'Set rgData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mail_Inventory").Range("A2:H" & currentinventory + 2)
'Set rgCriteria = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mail_Inventory").Range("AP5:AP6")
'Set rgOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mail_Inventory").Range("AS2:AZ2")

Set rgData = Range("A2:H" & currentinventory + 2)
Set rgCriteria = Range("AP5:AP6")
Set rgOutput = Range("AS2:AZ2")

rgData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rgCriteria, CopytoRange:=rgOutput

'wks.Range("A2:H" & currentinventory + 2).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=wks.Range("AP5:AP6"), CopyToRange:=wks.Range("AS2:AZ2")

'filteredcurrent = wks.Range("AS1").Value

'Me.ListBox2.Clear
'Me.ListBox2.RowSource = wks.Range("AS2:AV" & filteredcurrent + 2)
```

Comment: Try referencing the worksheet in you range variables, using `wks` with the three `rg` variables, e.g. `rgData = wks.Range`?

Comment: @GMalc I tried that and it didnt work :/

Comment: I am convinced at this point that it is something wrong with the excel program. I have tried tons of variants of code and nothing seems to work. It only seems to work when I use a xlfilterinplace, but I do not want the excel itself to get all mess up (with the disappearing rows and such)